# "During the proof search" vs "during searching the proof"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, syntactic-analysis, academia

I am writing an academic paper and use "during searching the proof" in my paper.
But my friend suggested me to use "during the proof search".
I also feel "during the proof search" is better than "during searching the proof",
but I cannot understand the reason for my feeling.

Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think a real noun, if available, would look better than a gerund where a noun-form word is needed.

Comment: During searching is awkward. During the search is good, and while searching is also possible.

Comment: While searching for the proof.

Comment: @Pedant Thanks for your help! I understand the question better now.

Comment: @Peter Many thanks for your kind and warm help!

Comment: @HotLicks I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: *During the search **for** proof.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for your suggestion! I think this is more accurate than my phrase!